# @ControllerAdvise is not catching UnrecognizedPropertyException exception - Springboot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a problem where I am trying to catch an exception from Entity class and get it handled by @ControllerAdvise 's exception handler method

below is the method under Entity class (I am trying map a Json String which has saved Blob in my db)

```
@Entity
@Table("mytable")
@Getters
@Setters
public class myData{
private String id;

@Lob
private String dbData;

@Transient
private Data data;

public Data getData() throws JsonProcessingException{
 if(data == null){
  ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper()
  data = mapper.readValue(dbData, Data.class);
 }
 return data;
}
}
```

**GlobalException Handler**

```
@ControllerAdvise
public class MainExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

 // other methods

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(Exception e){

// log exception

}

@ExceptionHandler(JsonProcessingException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleJsonException(JsonProcessingException e){

// log exception

}
```

}

**Controller Class**

```
@Autowired
DataService dataService;

@PostMapping("/api/getData")
public ResponseEntiry<Data> getData(@RequestBody Payload payload){

Data data = dataService.fetchData(payload);
ResponseEntity<Data> response= new ResponseEntity<>(data, HttpStatus.Ok);

return response; // the exception getting raised when it sending this response

}
```

**Service Class**

```
@Autowired
DataRepository dataRepo;

public Data fetchData(Payload payload){

return dataRepo.findById(payload.getID());

}
```

When the data is not properly mapped it's throwing an exception and I am getting 500 error in post man but not able to catch this exception and log it through @ControllerAdvise

**Please help**

**Update 1:**
tried to implement httpMessageNotReadble method but still no luck

Comment: Could you add the code of your `@RestControllerAdvice`  / `@ControllerAdvice` implementation?

Comment: @DanielWosch added the skeleton code for this

Comment: Could you share your controller and stacktrace ?

Comment: Can you add `final HttpServletRequest request` as parameter to the handlers and give it a try. AFAIR I've faced a smiliar issue. Further use `@RestControllerAdvice` which extends `@ControllerAdvice` by `@ResponseBody` which bounds the return value to the response body

Comment: Where in the code do you call this method getData() ?

Comment: I am not calling it manually.

Comment: it's getting called when controller is returning the result.

Comment: @Kai-ShengYang  added the controller, stack trace I can not add as it's in client machine but it's raising a UnrecognizedPropertyException